# Make a outbound voice call using Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I recently was introduced to Google [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/). I want to make an outbound voice call, let's say a to a phone number using Dialogflow. I have searched the forums- Google groups, Dialogflow, StackOverflow but could not find any solution nor any documentation. Hence this question,

Is it possible to make voice calls to a phone number using Dialogflow? If yes, any reference to it is very much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look into this: https://voximplant.com/solutions/dialogflow-connector

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the first answer, as far as I tried I couldn't get AoG/Dialogflow to make a phone call either. So what I did was just setup a simple API server with one endpoint to response redirect to `tel:123-456-789` like my Rails code below.

```
class CallController < ApplicationController
  def make_call
    redirect_to "tel:+66-#{params[:tel]}"
  end
end
```

Then add a BasicCard or Link out suggestion in Dialogflow to the link of that endpoint. With this setup clicking on the response will bring up the dialer with phone number ready.

Answer (score 3):

Simply make an outbound call through an automated script from any other providers such as twillio and as soon as user receive the call redirect your call to dialogflow number, so your user will be talking to dialogflow, hope this isea will help since dialogflow do not provide outbound calls so far, may be in future but no such announcements no plans of outbound calls sofar may be because they are nlp platform not VoIP provider

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow is NLP service and need to be integrated with some other platform, for example Actions on Google. 
In context of AoG it's not possible to do a call from Actions. If you want you can do it like below but it's not good way for user and I made it only as POC.

1. Have website with phone number as a link to which should be call make
2. Have JS script on website which is clicking it when opened
3. Use LinkOutSuggestion which is opening this site. Opening it on mobile will open phone dialer and will let user to make call

Comment: Read question carefully before answering it.